# A pointer that increases address by exactly 9 bytes

Tags: c++, c

Is there a proper way to declare a pointer that jumps 9 bytes when I increment it?

An example:

```
sometype* ptr = 0x0;
ptr+1; //ptr points now to 0x9
ptr+2; //ptr points now to 0x12
```

Comment: Yes, if `sizeof(sometype)==9` is true

Comment: Think about this: For a pointer `ptr`, doing `*(ptr + x)` is equivalent to doing `ptr[x]`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: the interface is a shared Memory. that memory contains blocks of 9 bytes that i have to interpret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct`-based solutions won't generally work unless the code specifically controls padding.

However, if we do this (using two `typedef`s for clarity)

```
typedef char base_type[9];
typedef base_type *some_type;
```

or (avoiding the need for the first `typedef`, but making things a little more cryptic)

```
typedef char (*some_type)[9];
```

then, given an appropriately initialised variable of type `some_type`, incrementing will increase by `9` characters.

Comment: Thank you.
that's exacly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @james Be aware that still can cause problems if your hardware has alignment restrictions, depending on how you're interpreting the 9 bytes accessed via your pointer.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Any solution involving structs is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Lundin why would solution with an unaligned struct not work?

Comment: @REACHUS Because there is no standard way to ensure that a struct does not have padding. The best you can do is a static assert that blocks the program from compiling if padding is present. `#pragma pack`, `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` etc are not standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `char` is required to not have alignment requirement

Comment: @M.M - "`char` is required to not have alignment requirement" - That's exactly my point.  Since `char` doesn't have alignment restrictions but whatever `sometype` is *can*, using `char` to force unaligned access **will** violate any alignment restrictions on `sometype`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle arrays have the same alignment requirement as their element type, so `char[9]` also cannot be unaligned

Comment: @M.M "arrays have the same alignment requirement as their element type, so char[9] also cannot be unaligned"  What evidence do you have that the OP wants to interpret his 9 bytes as an array of `char`?  How do you know it isn't a `struct { double d; char flag };` or something similar?  All the OP who posted the question has said is "Is there a proper way to declare a pointer that jumps 9 bytes when I increment it?"  He said **nothing** about what makes up those 9 bytes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle My comments are in the context of this answer which suggests using `char[9]` as the type to achieve OP's goal

Comment: @M.M - Glad you agree that it's unsafe to interpret those nine bytes as anything other than a `char[9]` else alignment issues will arise on any platform that has alignment restrictions on the interpreted type.  And performance issues will likely arise on any platform because of misaligned loads and stores.

Comment: I answered the question as asked:  a way to declare a pointer that, when incremented, would step by 9 bytes.   All I gave, in this answer, was a type of pointer which does that.   The OP gave no information about what the OP might do with an address obtained in such a manner, and I did not bother to speculate.   I also did not suggest, in any way, that I gave the only valid possible answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a struct, which will hold exactly 9 bytes, thus your pointer to that structure variables will be incremented by 9.

However, your structure may get [padded/memory aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) by the compiler (typically to the multiplication of 8 bytes). To avoid it, you could use GCC-specific attribute `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct padded1 {
    int var1;     
    char var2;
    int var3;  
};

struct padded2 {
    char data[9]; // my compiler still not apply padding here
};

struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) unpadded {
    char data[9];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Size of padded struct:   %ld\n", sizeof(struct padded1));
    printf("Size of padded struct:   %ld\n", sizeof(struct padded2));
    printf("Size of unpadded struct: %ld\n", sizeof(struct unpadded));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `struct padded2` was still unpadded on my platform.

Answer (score 0):

As @SingerofTheFall said, you can achive this by some tricks like

```
char *input = "0123456789";

struct move_struct {
    char c[3];
};

int main() {
    cout << "size: " << sizeof(move_struct) << endl;

    move_struct * temp_ptr = (move_struct *)(input);
    ++temp_ptr;

    char *result = (char *)(temp_ptr);

    cout << "Expected: "<< (input+sizeof(move_struct)) << "\n"
         << "Result:   " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

But ofcourse be aware of some compiler optimizations and just for me you doing something wrong :)

Comment: Should be `cout << "Expected: "<< input+3 << "\n"` so that it properly demonstrates the bug in this code that strikes when struct padding is appended.